# Oracle SQL Developer (4.1.1) Mac OSX install issues (El Capitan)

Tags: oracle, macos, oracle-sqldeveloper, osx-elcapitan

I am attempting to install Oracle SQL Developer Version 4.1.1. onto my MacBook Pro after installing OS X El Capitan. After I download the application and attempt to click on the icon to install it, the application's loading prompt appears and the "loading" bar moves about 5% to the part where it says "registering extensions" right above the loading bar. The application then crashes (no crash report, or anything appears afterwards).

After searching online I cannot find anyone else having this issue.

On a possibly related note - I attempted to install Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.1 on my Parallels Windows 8.1 Virtual Machine and had the same issue. Not sure if this stems from the same reason that my OS X install fails.

Help? suggestions? Im running out of ideas.

Comment: cd to your $HOME directory, and nuke the .sqldeveloper subdirectory. try running sqldev again

Comment: @that jeff smith - This solution did not work. Now the initial loading screen for SQLDeveloper will not show up. Can you please provide more assistance?

Comment: make sure it can find the java - i talk about that here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2014/12/java-8-on-a-mac-with-sql-developer-4-1/

Comment: I was successfully able to find the java. Thank you for the helpful article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run in terminal:

```
/Applications/SQLDeveloper.app/Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh
```

to view errors.

My error was

```
mkdir: /Users/gs/.sqldeveloper/4.1.0: Permission denied"
```

Solution:

```
sudo mv ~/.sqldeveloper ~/sqldeveloper.old
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the contents of your /Applications/SQLDeveloper.app

Edit /Contents/MacOS/sqldeveloper.sh

Add export JAVA_HOME pointing to your latest Java 1.8 version.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
```

This helped me.

Full `sqldeveloper.sh` file for SQL Developer 4.1.1.

```
#!/bin/bash 
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home
here="${0%/*}"
cd "${here}"
cd ../Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
bash ./sqldeveloper >>/dev/null
```

Comment: #!/bin/bash
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
here="${0%/*}"
cd "${here}"
cd ../Resources/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
bash ./sqldeveloper >>/dev/nul
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home  <br /> this is what I get, but its not working with your suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your shell file for clarity?

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but this solution still does not resolve my issue.

Comment: Installed new 4.1.1 version and updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you. Part of my issue was the deprecated .sh file. Thank you for updating. That fixed some of the issues, but not all of them - really helpful though!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, I had to download the JDK for the install to work. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an issue related to **attached external monitor**. I had moved my primary display to an external monitor and then disconnecting external displays allows me to start the app. Plugging the external display in and the application moves to the primary external monitor.

Got info after googling and read that posts from [oracle community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/4266739?start=0&tstart=0)